# Problems Turning String of HTML to jQuery Object then Parsing Through It

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-parsing

I have set up a little snippet that will take an autoresponder code for email marketing from a `textarea` and when the textarea loses focus, it parses what was just pasted and grabs some attributes and elements from that, and puts them in separate input fields.

The problem is that the code I've written apparently doesn't do this right and for some autoresponder codes, it won't grab the form's action URL, some it does, it usually has no problem grabbing all of the hidden input fields, and then sometimes does not want to grab the name or email fields 'name' attributes.

The code is pretty straight forward. I tried using `.find()` instead of `.filter()` and it seems to just act at random. Some things work that didn't work with `.find()`, some things don't work that did work with `.find()`. I don't think that's the root of the problem but may help to explain what's going on.

**Edit** It seems to work *"better"* with `.find()`.

I just have no idea why it would behave like this, any ideas?

Example form HTML that is inserted to a textarea [is here](http://pastebin.com/wR9r96pA). (It is messy but I didn't write it!) -- This code would be in a `textarea` in which the code below parses it when it loses focus.

**Edit**: The root of the problem seems to the the `<form action="#">` part.

- An [Aweber Code](http://pastebin.com/dzMj9tSh) for example, will not retrieve the Form URL (`action` attribute)
- An [Ebizac Code](http://pastebin.com/ai36FJsk) will not retrieve the Form URL
- An [Imnica Code](http://pastebin.com/TUifMLFx) works fine now apparently(?).
- There's no problems with the [GetResponse Code](http://pastebin.com/VLkMrPgr).

[**Most recent JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpK9F/5/) <- code here

Comment: Does this "$j( this ).val() );" retrieve an element id? Showing your HTML would be helpful.

Comment: Code like `if( arcode != '' )` isn't doing what you seem to think, because `arcode` is going to be a jQuery object and so it will _always_ be not equal to a string.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'll try it with `if( $j( this ).val() != '' )` and update with the results. -- __EDIT__ I get the same results.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down which inputs cause trouble and which don't? (By, say, `console.log`ging the raw HTML and whenever you detect a problem?)

Comment: @Inerdial It seems to be at random. With some autoresponder codes it won't grab the form action URL and email input. With some it works (Aweber) and with some it gets all fields but the form action URL.

Comment: Also `console.log` returns all the HTML as expected, but jQuery is having problems parsing it. :)

Comment: Is the example HTML you linked to something that _works_ with your code? If so, can you give an example of something that _doesn't_ work? By the way, the `if( name != '' )` and `if( email != '' )` tests towards the end of your code have the same problem I mentioned above where you're comparing a jQuery object to a string (though the path it then takes should still produce the right end result).

Comment: Also, your `.each()` loop assumes there will be only one input for "name" and one for "input" (but allows for multiple hidden fields), so if there is more than one "name" input it will only pick up the _last_ one...

Comment: @nnnnnn Yep it should only add one email/name input but thank you for pointing out the `if( name != '' )` issue, I hadn't even noticed. I will update my question soon with more examples and explanations of what 'works' and what doesn't.

Comment: Here's a simple jsfiddle with the code (from just before your last edit): http://jsfiddle.net/fpK9F/ - just so people can play around with it.

Comment: @nnnnnn I updated the question with some autoresponder code examples and what they do, and an updated JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem with the html that doesn't work like your AWeber example is that it is not contained within a single top-level parent element, which means that when you parse it to create the `arcode` jQuery object that object contains the `<form>` element as a top level element. That in turn means that the `.find()` method - which looks for descendent elements - doesn't find anything since there are no additional `<form>` elements that are children. (You can test this for yourself by checking `arcode.length` or using `arcode.each()` to log the tagnames of the elements in `arcode`.)

Your example that did work happened to be wrapped in a top-level `<div>`, so it didn't have this problem.

So my suggested fix for this is just to wrap the entered html in a `<div>` element yourself, thus making everything work with `.find()`. And then simplify your function, since the following short version does all that your original function did:

```
$j( '#jwsqz_autocode' ).blur( function() {

    var thehtml = "<div>" + $j( this ).val() + "</div>";
    var arcode = $j( thehtml );

    $j('#jwsqz_autoformurl').val( arcode.find('form').attr('action') );
    $j('#jwsqz_arnameinput').val(
         arcode.find('input[type="text"][name*="name"]').attr('name') );
    $j('#jwsqz_aremailinput').val(
         arcode.find('input[type="text"][name*="email"]').attr('name') );

    var hiddens = "";

    arcode.find( 'input[type="hidden"]' ).each( function() {
       hiddens += $j( this ).prop( 'outerHTML' ) + "\n";
    });

    $j( '#jwsqz_autohidden' ).val( hiddens );

});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fpK9F/6/ (seems to handle your example cases).

You'll notice I've made use of the [jQuery attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) with `[name*="email"]`.

Note that if tests like the following from your code are redundant:

```
if( hiddens != '' )
   $j( '#jwsqz_autohidden' ).val( hiddens );
else
   $j( '#jwsqz_autohidden' ).val( '' );
```

In the `else` case you are setting the value that was in the `hiddens` variable anyway, so you can replace the whole structure with just the part from the `if` - as I did in my code above.

UPDATE: For a case-insensitive test of the `name` attribute's value you can do this:

```
    $j('#jwsqz_aremailinput').val(
         arcode.find('input[type="text"]')
               .filter(function(){ return /email/i.test(this.name); })
               .attr('name') );
```

(You don't have to use a regular expression, the key point is the `.filter()` function.)

Case insensitive demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fpK9F/7/

Comment: Oops, sorry about the duplicate answer.

Comment: One small issue I noticed, in my case sometimes the email and name attributes have uppercase letters. Is there a way to check for that easily? I see your code works, I appreciate it, would love to accept your answer if you could include that quickly. :)